# Are my Python threads tripping over each other with requests?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests

I have a program that needs to access data from an API. I need to get a list from it and then for every item in that list, request more data from the API. When I get a list, I get them in batches of 50 when there are around 600 items on this list. I thought that I could do this using requests and threading. Here is what it looks like:

I have essentially a helper method to call the API:

```
call_api_method(method, token, params={}):
     params_to_send = params.copy()
     params_to_send['auth'] = token
     response = requests.get('{0}/rest{1}'.format(DOMAIN, method), params = params_to_send)
     return response.json()
```

I then have a recursive threading function to get all info. I thought I could use threads to go ahead and request the next batch of info while making threads to request the info per item:

```
def import_item_info(auth_token, start = None):
     if start is None:
          start = 0
     threads = []
     result = call_api_method('get_list', auth_token, {'start': start})
     #the call returns next which is the index of the next batch
     if result['next']:
          thread = threading.Thread(target=import_item_info, args=(auth_token, result['next'])
          thread.start()
          threads.append(thread)
     for list_item in result['result']:
          thread = threading.Thread(target=get_item_info, args=(auth_token, item['ID'])
          thread.start()
          threads.append(thread)
     for thread in threads:
          thread.join()
```

This is get_item_info, which makes a call to the api using the id of the item to get the specific details about the item:

```
 def get_item_info(auth_token, item_id):
     item = call_api_method('get_item', auth_token, {'id': item_id})
     print(item['key'])
```

I've abstracted a lot of the info, but essentially what is going on is that sometimes the requests.get returns something slightly garbled and I get a JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0).

I highly suspect that this is a threading problem because the first request goes through just fine. I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: what is real url ? Did you tried `get_item_info` without thread ? Did you get the same problem ? Did you print `response.text` or `response.content` to see what you get ? maybe you get some useful information - maybe API sends you some warning or there is different problem with network. Did you print full url to test it directly in web browser ? Maybe you create url which doesn't work in web browser too.

Comment: get_item_info works perfectly fine without threads. No problem with it. I printed off the item and the item's key just fine. Full url works just fine as well.

As for what the real url is: it's our company's cloud CRM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. Sorry... I thought I checked but apparently I hit the query limit and that's why it is starting to do weird things.